# xcode - filter xml data for UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, xcode

I'm using xCode 4.3.2. In this project, i have read the xml data and put it in a uiTableView, But here i want to list the output data (more than '4000') price only. 
How can i set a condition for this? 
Could you please help me?

my XML:

```
<oembed>
<Company><name>ABC</name><price>2000</price></Company>
<Company><name>JP</name><price>4000</price></Company>
<Company><name>VB</name><price>5000</price></Company>
</oembed>
```

ViewController.m

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName 
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict 
{

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"oembed"]) 
    {
        books = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Company"]) 
    {
        aBook = [[Book alloc] init];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string 
{ 

    if(!currentElementValue) 
        currentElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
    else
        [currentElementValue appendString:string];

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"oembed"])
        return;

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Company"]) {

        [books addObject:aBook];

        [aBook release];
        aBook = nil;
    }
    else 
        [aBook setValue:currentElementValue forKey:elementName];

    [currentElementValue release];
    currentElementValue = nil;
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: check for this condition when creating the cell .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try filtering your `books` array before displaying the data in the table.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.price >= 4000"];
NSArray *filtered = [books filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Note that this code assumes you're using some sort of a dictionary or a custom object which has a property named `price`.